# How to get the same random number twice?

Tags: c#, winforms, random

In my code we can see that I am pulling a random line from ListBox by using a random.Next. The problem is that if I want to check the same line for number of characters I'm using a new random number which causes some problems.

How can I use first random number to be used in my IF statement?

```
SendKeys.Send(lbMessage.Items[random.Next(lbMessage.Items.Count)].
    ToString().Substring(currentChar++, 1));

if (currentChar == lbMessage.Items[random.Next(lbMessage.Items.Count)].ToString().Length)
{
    SendKeys.Send("{enter}");
    tmrSpace.Enabled = false;
    currentChar = 0;
}
```

Comment: If you know how to get same number, its not random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the first random number in a local variable and use it later, like this:

```
int ran = random.Next(lbMessage.Items.Count);
SendKeys.Send(lbMessage.Items[ran].ToString().Substring(currentChar++, 1));

if (currentChar == lbMessage.Items[ran].ToString().Length) {
    SendKeys.Send("{enter}");
    tmrSpace.Enabled = false;
    currentChar = 0;
}
```

Comment: But if variable is called again doesn't the random change? I have tried this and it seem to generate a new random seed.

Comment: Then you need to save the generated random number somewhere else in your code, where you're certain that it won't change.

Answer (score 1):

Simply back it up to a variable :-)

```
var rnd = random.Next(lbMessage.Items.Count);
SendKeys.Send(lbMessage.Items[rnd].
    ToString().Substring(currentChar++, 1));

if (currentChar == lbMessage.Items[rnd].ToString().Length)
{
    SendKeys.Send("{enter}");
    tmrSpace.Enabled = false;
    currentChar = 0;
}
```

Comment: This seem to generate a new random also. I have tried this but seed seems to change.

Comment: No, you must be doing something wrong. `rnd` will be the same in second and third line.

Comment: @NewHelpNeeder - this generates a random number once (on the first line) and re-uses it in the send keys and the if statement.  How are you getting different numbers?

Comment: everytime you run the method this is in, you will get a different random number.  the rnd value will stay the same only until rnd goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

how about storing the randomness temporarily?

```
int randomness = random.Next(lbMessage.Items.Count);
SendKeys.Send(lbMessage.Items[randomness].ToString().Substring(currentChar++, 1));

if (currentChar == lbMessage.Items[randomness].ToString().Length)
{
    SendKeys.Send("{enter}");
    tmrSpace.Enabled = false;
    currentChar = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
int index = random.Next(lbMessage.Items.Count);

string value = lbMessage.Items[index].ToString(); 

SendKeys.Send(value.Substring(currentChar++, 1));

if (currentChar == value.Length)
{
    SendKeys.Send("{enter}");
    tmrSpace.Enabled = false;
    currentChar = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a seed value to the Random() constructor, you'll get the same random values every time.

```
Random random = new Random(86);  // Seed can be any Int32 value
```

Is that what you're trying to accomplish? I would have thought Sergio's answer was what you're looking for, but it doesn't seem to be.